# Can set-car! and set-cdr! be implemented as macros?

Tags: lisp, scheme, metaprogramming, abstract-syntax-tree

Is it possible to implement `set-car!` and `set-cdr!` *portably* as macros using `set!` in Scheme?  Or would this require special access to the underlying storage system?

I'm asking because I'm implementing my own Scheme interpreter, and I'd like to have as much as possible out in scheme code.

My first attempt on `set-cdr!` was:

```
(define-syntax set-cdr!
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((set-cdr! location value)
     (set! location (cons (car location) value)))))
```

This *mostly* works, but not for circular lists:

```
#; mickey> (define x (list 1 2))
#; mickey> x
(1 2)
#; mickey> (set-cdr! x x)
#; mickey> x
(1 1 2)
```

Wrapping the macro body in `let` did not help me either, because when I do `(set! (cons (car location) value)`, then `value` has already been evaluated to be `'(1 2)`.

Comment: Why not use mpair library in Dr Racket? you could use (require scheme/mpair) and then say (define list mlist)...(define cons mcons)...(define set-car! set-mcar!).. etc. But then all your lists will be mutable by default.

Comment: @Rajesh: Because I've written a nearly feature-complete Scheme from scratch in C++ :-) I just want to move out as many functions as I can into the library as scheme files, instead of having many functions implemented in C++.  But thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: surgical functions must be primitives. that's it.

Comment: The following works in Chicken Scheme, but not in Chibi, Guile, mzscheme nor mit-scheme:

`(define a (cons 1 2))`
`(set! (cdr a) a)`

which creates a circular list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In

```
(set! location (cons (car location) value))
```

the expression `(cons (car location) value)` allocates a *new* pair.

The purpose of `set-cdr!` is to mutate an existing pair.

So implementing `set-cdr!` does require "special" access to the underlying storage.

Comment: But I thought scheme only required a very strict core containing typically if/cond, lambda, quote, set! and some other primitives (plus basic data types and constants).  I'm not sure if `cons` is the problem.  Rather, it's that we can't get the address of `value` (it is evaluated).

Comment: Well, if you *really* want to you can simulate pairs using closures, but that is *very* ineffecient. See the answer below.

Comment: Of course, but that's not what I want. :) I've got `set!`, and I want `set-car!` and `set-cdr!`.  Anyway, implementing `set!` in terms of the others works, of course.

Comment: I see `set!` and `set-car!` as different. Let's say a location `x` contains (has a pointer to) a pair, then setting (using set!) just puts a different pointer in the location. On the other hand `set-car!` changes something "inside" a value. --- But to answer your question, you have to specify which level your interpreter works. Are you simulating your own memory (say using a giant vector of bytes) or are you simply using values from the underlying Scheme system? If you are inheriting pairs from the underlying system, you need to inherit `set-car!` too.

Comment: Suppose for the moment that we want to implement `set-car!` with `set!`. How should pairs be represented? The only think `set!` can do is to store a new value into a location to which a variable is bound. Thus we are forced to choose an representation in which the two parts of the pair is two locations each bound to a variable. The only (reasonable?) way to allocate such a value is to construct a closure. Therefore all solutions in which `set!` alone is used to implement `set-car!` will look more or less as the answer in which pairs were represented as closures.

Comment: Ok, I've pondered about this for some time, and I think you are right about cons() creating a new pair.  It all depends on how you implement your Scheme.  I'm doing it in C++, so it's easy to implement set!, set-car! and set-cdr! in C++, of course, but it would be even greater if I could move some of them out in Scheme source code files and include them in a library.  Unfortunately, I think you are right: I need access to the addresses.

Comment: In Scheme, every thing is an automatically dereferenced pointer. So you need special ***primitives*** for *that*.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of implementing Cons, Car, Cdr, Set-car! and Set-cdr! using closures.

```
(define (Cons x y)
  (lambda (message . val)
    (cond
      [(eq? message 'car) x]
      [(eq? message 'cdr) y]
      [(eq? message 'set-car!) 
       (set! x (car val))]
      [(eq? message 'set-cdr!) 
       (set! y (car val))]
      [else 'unknown-message])))

(define (Car pair)
  (pair 'car))

(define (Cdr pair)
  (pair 'cdr))

(define (Set-cdr! pair val)
  (pair 'set-cdr! val))

(define (Set-car! pair val)
  (pair 'set-car! val))

(define p (Cons 1 2))
(Car p)
(Cdr p)
(Set-car! p 3)
(Car p)
(Set-cdr! p 4)
(Cdr p)
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically you can implement set! without set!, but I don't think you can implement set-car!/set-cdr! without either mutating pairs or simulating pairs (like soegaard's example)

Since it seems you're making your Scheme implementation in Scheme I would have used set-car!/set-cdr! to implement it in the interpreter or just not implemented them at all. I would have started with define, if, quote, pair?, eq?, cons, car and cdr (similar to [The roots of LISP](http://paulgraham.com/rootsoflisp.html), but more schemish) to have a base minimum implementation to start with and then enhanced it further.

Anyway.. Your implementation, if you do implement it should be able to do this:

```
(define odds (list 1 3 5 7 9 11))
(set-car! (cddr odds) #f)
odds
===> (1 3 #f 7 9 11)
```

Comment: I'm implementing it in C++.  It's super-easy to implement set!, set-car! and set-cdr! from within C++, because I have access to the pointers I'm using, and it works nicely.  But it would be even better to have only set! and then implement set-car! etc in a Scheme source code library.  Alas...

Comment: While set-car! and set-cdr! actually changes a data pointer, set! actually is very different. set! can be used both for parameters as well as global variables and within a procedure it's the environment of that procedure which is the one you are changing. If you are implementing an interpreter you need to implement frames. If you are implementing a compiler, then you can remove set! by wrapping the closure in a another lambda where you box variables that mutate eg. a generator might translate to  (lambda (x) (let ((x (cons x))) (lambda (n) (let ((old (car x)) (set-car! x (+ old n)) old)))))))